# Connecting to an MQ: Newbie question

Tags: ibm-mq

I am a novice with Websphere MQ and require some novice help.
I am using Websphere MQ Explorer to connect to a queue but do not know how to write the connection string. I have all the details (host, port, channel, queue manager name) but do not know how to put them together correctly as a connection string.

Can any help this novice?

Thanks

Comment: I feel like more info is needed on this.  Are you asking how to connect to the Queue Manager via MQExplorer or how to connect to the queue via some programming language?  Are you connecting to a local or remote queue manager?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to get you started (assuming your queue manager under default configuration):

1. Queue Managers->Context Menu->Add Remote Queue Manager
2. Fill in Queue manager name:
   Select Connect directly
   Next
3. Fill in:
   Host name or IP Address:
   Port number:
   Server-connection channel:
   Next
   Next
4. If you have a user configured usually mqm user, you will need to tick the "Enable user identification" here and fill in the user/pass here.
5. Next, Next, Finish.

As you see, you might need to fill in other information such as SSL if you configured it at the target queue manager.

Then you should be able to see the queue manager in the tree.  Click on the Queues icon to find the queue you care about.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you are using the latest WebSphere MQ Explorer which is now a stand-alone download.  You can find it at [SupportPac MS0T](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMS0T) which is available from the [main SupportPac page](http://ibm.co/SupptPacs).  There are significant advantages to using that version, including Explorer Plug-Ins for WMQ FTE, WebSphere Message Broker, the MS0P plug-in which parses event messages, and more.

The screen shot below shows the connection dialog in the latest WMQ Explorer.  It has separate fields for hostname (or IP address). port and channel.  Just plug in the appropriate values and you are good to go!

[image]